# Duplicates in Pub/Sub-Dataflow-BigQuery pipeline

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

Consider the following setup:

- Pub/Sub
- Dataflow: **streaming** job for validating events from Pub/Sub, unpacking and writing to BigQuery
- BigQuery

We have counters on the valid events that pass through our Datafow Pipeline and observe the **counters are higher than the amount of events** that were available in Pub/Sub.

> Note: It *seems* we also see duplicates in BigQuery, but we are still investigating this.

The following error can be observed in the Dataflow logs:

```
Pipeline stage consuming pubsub took 1h35m7.83313078s and default ack deadline is 5m. 
Consider increasing ack deadline for subscription projects/<redacted>/subscriptions/<redacted >
```

Note that the Dataflow job is started when there are already millions of messages waiting in Pub/Sub.

Questions:

- Can this cause duplicate events to be picked up by the pipeline?
- Is there anything we can do to alleviate this issue?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to purge the PubSub subscription message queue by launching the Dataflow job in batch mode. Then run it in streaming mode for the usual operation. Like this, you will be able to start from a clean basis your streaming job and not have a long list of enqueued messages.

In addition, it's the power of Dataflow (and beam) to be able to run in streaming and in batch the same pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @guillaime! the current setup is mainly to test how fast we will be able to consume messages. We've setup snapshots to test different configurations of our dataflow job (machine type, etc.). As dataflow is supposed to provide exactly-once semantics for this configuration, I'm a bit surprised that we are seeing duplicate events and these long ack times. Can it be because dataflow is retrieving them long after their publish time as they were in Pub/Sub for quite long? if so, this could also mean that we'd lose the semantics once we have a data spike... :/

Comment: You are testing the best configuration to size correctly your VM, correct? What is your expected deadline to push in production?

Comment: Keep in mind that dataflow adapt the configuration according to the traffic and the latency between the the event publication and the event processing (named watermark). According to the evolution of it (and other parameters), Dataflow chooses to scale up and down the pipeline's number of node. The size of your VM and the number of workers have also impact on the processing time. Your use case is not relevant. you start with a huge amount of data, no ramp up!

Comment: Thanks! (Aiming for production in a few weeks) we are indeed looking into setting a number of workers to start with and comparing different machine types. My main concern is that events are processed and counted twice, which should not happen, even in the face of scaling and re-execution. I am aware that this does not hold for side-effects, but we are not using any of those :) See also https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/after-lambda-exactly-once-processing-in-google-cloud-dataflow-part-1